# postgres issue for native query while inserting\retrieving null

Tags: postgresql, hibernate, jpa

Hi I am using JPA with native queries while working with postgres. I have a db field called quote_permid with data type as numeric. The value is NULL in table for a particular record. When I am using REST API with POST to update the record I am getting below error

> 

2024-01-11T14:53:38,021 ERROR [http-nio-8080-exec-2] SqlExceptionHelper id= marker= - ERROR: column "quote_permid" is of type numeric but expression is of type bytea
Hint: You will need to rewrite or cast the expression.

> 

I am thinking of using entity manager however I not sure if I can make modifications in native queries.